# Parsing serial data with a Structure Record in Python3

Tags: python, parsing, serial-port

I'm trying to parse data that I received from a monitor via a serial port. I've successfully coded a script in Python to retrieved the data from the monitor as a byte string and did the necessary data conversions as per the ISO3309 Standard and finally performed a checksum to ensure data integrity. Below is the extracted data.

```
[198, 2, 40, 4, 0, 0, 131, 35, 158, 94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 22, 1, 1, 44, 2, 4, 189, 189, 255, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 131, 35, 158, 94, 51, 58, 0, 0, 0, 18, 2, 128, 10, 129, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 4, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 4, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 203, 29, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41, 8, 41, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 255, 141, 2, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 173, 1, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 0, 131, 35, 158, 94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 2, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 4, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 73, 13, 0, 0, 176, 192, 0, 0, 226, 1, 0, 0, 198, 2, 0, 0, 240, 127, 170, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 49, 28, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 195, 165, 0, 0, 195, 165, 1, 128, 72, 8, 160, 15, 32, 78, 208, 7, 208, 7, 112, 23, 80, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 7, 112, 23, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 141]
```

I have the structure record.Please see attached 
It doesn't help that the record is probably in written in C. However, my question is for the Header. If, Struct: is just a custom variable with multiple data types. Does the structure of the Header correspond directly to the first integers in my list of data? So for example: r_len =
 198, r_nbr = 2, r_time = 0? And do I continue to move down the list sequentially to obtain the sub records? If so, time is defined as the number of seconds since 1.1.1970. So how can that be from a single integer?  I would be very thankful for any hints you can provide. Thank you for reading my long post.
[Structure Record for the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9uQ5.jpg)
[image: Structure Record page 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Robert and thank you for the task i've just had a joy with!

The spec definitely means it passes the data in bytes, described by that C-like structure. I can't see how you did read the data, but the guessing was you've got here exactly a list of bytes, since every value there is less then 256.

So, looking through the structure i can try to convert it in a human-readable form. This is done with [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html) module in python:

```
b = bytes(l)
hdr_data = struct.unpack_from('<hBBHLBBHH', b)
print(hdr_data)
```

### Explanation

Here I consider `l` as an initial list of bytes. Given the structure of the record provided by you, i've constructed the format string for the header:

`hBBHLBBHH` means: short, byte, byte, word, dword, byte, byte, word, word.

`<` in the begining means that [byte-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is little-endian

The result printed is

```
(710, 40, 4, 0, 1587422083, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Here the first value is `r_len` and is equal 710. The lenght of you list `len(l)` is 711, so most probably my initial guessing about the format of the list and endianness is correct, and you have there one redundant byte in the end by an accident.

### Next step

Though we're mostly done with that one-liner, we haven't read sr_desc yet, and we didn't set up suitable name matching.

Let's change the unpacking line to consume `struct sr_desc[8]` as well:

```
hdr_data = struct.unpack_from('<hBBHLBBHH' + 'hB'*8, b)
```

Now we'll have it all in one tuple.

A very convenient way to access the fields is [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
from collections import namedtuple
D_O_hdr = namedtuple('D_O_hdr',
                     ('r_len', 'r_nbr', 'dri_level', 'plug_id', 
                      'r_time', 'n_subset', 'res', 'dest_plug_id',
                      'r_maintype',))

header = D_O_hdr(*hdr_data[:9])
print(header)
```

You can now see that you can easily access to each field, like `print(header.r_len)` and so on.

Same, but a litle bit more tricky, for `sr_data`:

```
struct_sr_desc = namedtuple('sr_desc', ('sr_offset', 'sr_type',))

sr_data = [struct_sr_desc(off, typ) 
           for off, typ in zip(hdr_data[9::2], hdr_data[10::2])]

# Just make sure we've got a list of 8 objects
assert len(sr_data) == 8
```

Here the problem was that we've needed to convert a plain list to a list of structures. `hdr_data[9::2]` takes every first field of `sr_desc` (i.e. `sr_offset`) and `hdr_data[10::2]` takes every second field. `zip` makes a pair of lists be a list of pairs.

`sr_data[3].type` contains 255, which means that you have only three subrecords in a structure, but unpacking them is already on you! Just don't forget that `sr_data[i].offset` contains an offset from the end of the header. That's mostly obvious since `sr_data[0].offset` is always `0` but anyway.

The complete script is here: https://repl.it/@FooBarrior/CreativePartialOpenlook

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! You went above and beyond. Thank you so much